# SQL wildcard for Field Name?

Tags: arcmap, sql, select-by-attribute

I'm wondering if there's anyway to use a wildcard character in a field name. Like using `["Species_%" = 'Hemlock']` instead of `["Species_1" = 'Hemlock'` OR `"Species_2" = 'Hemlock' ...]`.

I tried the way that I described but it didn't work. Does anyone know if it's possible with another method within the Select By Attributes window?

Comment: No, this is not possible. The best way to accomplish this is to normalize your attributes and have multiple species records per feature; then you can select those which meet the criteria.

Answer (score 1):

You can Paste this function into the Python window of ArcMap. Execute it from the same window. The selected features will be highlighted.
parameters are, select(LayerName, speciesName)

 eg. select('wildlife','hemlock')

```
def select(layerName, species):
    fields = ["objectid","species_1","species_2"]

    mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
    lyr = arcpy.mapping.Layer(layerName)

    bCursor = arcpy.da.SearchCursor(lyr,fields)

    # save each Objectid
    selectset = []
    for row in bCursor:
        if str(row[1]).upper() == species.upper():
            selectset.append(str(row[0]))
        elif str(row[2]).upper() == species.upper():
            selectset.append(str(row[0]))

    # build a where_clause such as "Objectid in (2,5,7)"
    if selectset:
        ids = list(set(selectset))
        where_clause = 'Objectid in ({})'.format(','.join(ids))
        arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management (layerName, "NEW_SELECTION", where_clause)
```